# subversion svn: E175013: forbidden - temporary

Tags: subversion

we´re using subversion with authentiation set

"AuthBasicProvider file ldap".

one special user for automated builds (via quickbuild) does exist on the file as well as on the LDAP server with the same username, but different password.

Most of the time the access works, but from time to time (every few days, usage is 24/7) we get an E175013: forbidden error what causes builds to fail (using the file credentials.

I would e.g. understand, if the first auth point was LDAP, this would maybe time out, and it tries file instead, but as file is first in the list, that´s not possible, or am I wrong here?

for other users, we sometimes have slow authentication, but did still work...

would be thankful for any ideas to solve / find the cause.